# Swapping colors of two pixels

Tags: java, sorting, pixel, bufferedimage

I must do n rounds of row pixel sorting of a buffered image, looping through each row and comparing the brightness of the current pixel to the one to the left of the current pixel. If the brightness of the current is less than the one to the left, I need to swap the colors of the pixels. This is my current code.

```
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int m = 0; m<n;m++){
            for (int y=0;y<img.getHeight();y++){
                for(int x =1; x<img.getWidth();x++){
                int temp = img.getRGB(x-1,y);
                int temp2 = img.getRGB(x, y);
                int gr = (int)brightness(temp);
                int gr2 = (int)brightness(temp2);
                if(gr2<gr){
                    result.setRGB(x, y, rgbColour(temp2,temp2,temp2));
                    result.setRGB(x-1, y, rgbColour(temp,temp,temp));
                }
            }
    }
    }
```

The methods I've been given are as follows.

```
 public static int getRed(int rgb) { return (rgb >> 16) & 0xff; }
public static int getGreen(int rgb) { return (rgb >> 8) & 0xff; }
public static int getBlue(int rgb) { return rgb & 0xff; }
public static int rgbColour(int r, int g, int b) {
    return (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
}
public static double brightness(int rgb) {
    int r = getRed(rgb);
    int g = getGreen(rgb);
    int b = getBlue(rgb);
    return 0.21*r + 0.72*g + 0.07*b;
}

public static BufferedImage convertToGrayscale(BufferedImage img) {
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(
            img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
        );
    for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
            int col = img.getRGB(x, y);
            int gr = (int)brightness(col);
            result.setRGB(x, y, rgbColour(gr, gr, gr));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: It seems what I'm doing isn't giving me the desired output.

Comment: `for (int m = 0; m<n;m++)` What is `n` here?

Comment: I need to "n" rounds of pixel sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You are not switching the values properly after the comparison:

```
for(int x =1; x<img.getWidth();x++){
    int temp = img.getRGB(x-1,y);
    int temp2 = img.getRGB(x, y);
...
    if (gr2 < gr) {
        result.setRGB(x, y, rgbColour(temp2,temp2,temp2)); // same as in img
        result.setRGB(x-1, y, rgbColour(temp,temp,temp)); // same as in img
    }
}
```

Try this if-clause instead:

```
    ...
    if (gr2 < gr) { // swap values in result
        result.setRGB(x-1, y, rgbColour(temp2,temp2,temp2));
        result.setRGB(x, y, rgbColour(temp,temp,temp));
    } else { // keep values in result same as in img
        result.setRGB(x, y, rgbColour(temp2,temp2,temp2));
        result.setRGB(x-1, y, rgbColour(temp,temp,temp));
    }
```